# On Wakanda Server, how can I access the current value of an attribute during a save / validate?

Tags: wakanda

I am building a **"change log"** feature for a **Wakanda** application. During the validate or save events on the server, I need to get access to the existing value of the attribute as it is in the datastore so I can record a before value and an after value.

At this point, the only solution I have found is to run a query in the validate event and retrieve the entity fresh from the datastore. Perhaps this is the best / only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution is to run a query in the validate event.
In the validate event function the word "**this**" refer to the new entity that will be saved.
You can get the existing entity by running the query (find()) : 
*ds.Item.find('ID = :1 ',  **this**.ID);*